# Particular data is not shown in a class based rest API 's detail page .It shows only attributes with no values. What will I do?

Tags: django, filter, django-rest-framework

I created a class based rest API successfully. The ProgramAPIView shows
all program in the Django rest framework. But the ProgramDetailAPIView
does not return the particular program's data in the restapi instead it       just shows the attributes with no value.Below is the django rest api:

```
 class ProgramAPIView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        programs = Program.objects.all()
        serailizer = ProgramSerializer(programs, many=True)
        return Response(serailizer.data, status=200)

class ProgramDetailAPIView(APIView):

    def get_object(self, pk):
        try:
            program = Program.objects.get(pk=pk)
        except Program.DoesNotExist:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    def get(self, request, pk):
        # get details of a single program
        program = self.get_object(pk)
        serializer = ProgramSerializer(program)
        return Response(serializer.data)
   

     Program List Page
        Program Api
        GET /program/

      [
            {
                "programCode": "116",
                "pro_name": "B.Sc. Engg. in EEE",
                "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/program/116/",
                "DepartmentID": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/departments/2/"
            },
            {
                "programCode": "115",
                "pro_name": "B.Sc. Engg. in CSE",
                "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/program/115/",
                "DepartmentID": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/departments/1/"
            }
        ]
    
   
     Program Detail Page
            Program Detail Api 
            GET /program/116/
         
               {
                "programCode": "",
                "pro_name": "",
                "DepartmentID": null
        }
        ]
```

Comment: How to Filter a Queryset in a ProgramDetailAPIView

Answer (score 0):

Your get_object() function returns None. In other words, this function does not return anything if exception does not happen. Correct it like this:

```
def get_object(self, pk):
    try:
        program = Program.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except Program.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
    else:
        return program
```

Besides, why don't you use DRF Generic Views? More info: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/